# simply check for calendar occurrences?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I'm trying to write an Android app that will return all the Events of a defined Calendar that will occur between two dates.
I found lots of tutos on the web to read/write events but none explain how to explicitly use the [Events table info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#events). In fact, I'm able to return all the events that start or end between the wanted interval but the result does not contain recurrent events. Well, it does, but only if the dtstart date is included in the interval. If an occurrence of that recurrent event is to happen during the interval, it does not show.

So, my question is: Is there a simple way to return also the recurrent events that **haven't started** in the dates interval but that will have an **occurrence in the dates interval**? Or am-I obliged to crawl into the rrule and rdate formulas FOR EACH recurrent event of the calendar to find-out if occurrences are set between the interval (witch seems to me very complicated)?
Below the code that enables me to return the events between 03/13/1984 at midnight and 03/13/1984 at midday, for the calendar who's id  = 5.

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(1984, 2, 13, 0, 0, 0);// 13 MARS 1984!!!
  long calMilSec = cal.getTimeInMillis();
  String[] l_projection = new String[]{"title", "dtstart", "dtend", "rrule"};
  Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_eventUri, l_projection, "calendar_id="+5+" AND dtstart>" + (calMilSec) + " AND dtstart<" + (calMilSec+43200000), null, "dtstart ASC");
  if (l_managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
      int l_cnt = 0;
      String l_title;
      long l_begin;
      long l_end;
      String l_rrule;
      StringBuilder l_displayText = new StringBuilder();
      int l_colTitle = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[0]);
      int l_colBegin = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
      int l_colEnd = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[2]);
      int l_colRule = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[3]);
      do {
          l_title = l_managedCursor.getString(l_colTitle);
          l_begin = l_managedCursor.getLong(l_colBegin);
          l_end = l_managedCursor.getLong(l_colEnd);
          l_rrule = l_managedCursor.getString(l_colRule);
          Date dateB = new Date(l_begin);
          Date dateE = new Date(l_end);
          SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("E-dd-MMM:HH:mm:ss-yyyy");
          dateFormat.format(dateB);
          dateFormat.format(dateE);
          l_displayText.append(l_title + "\n" + dateB + "\n" + dateE + "\n" + l_rrule + "\n----------------\n");
          ++l_cnt;
      } while (l_managedCursor.moveToNext() );
      calName = calName + l_displayText.toString();
  }
  testText.setText(calName);
```